# Right progress bar max/min values

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I got an problem with  tag, it makes the progress bar right, but i cant calculate right values to make that display from start to the end of bar. e.g.: that a game. I got 2431375 EXP, to next level i need 2438402 EXP. EXP never resets to zero, that mean if i reached new lvl, exp will continue counting from 2438402. So, i have not idea to display it right. Progress bar of exp is always almost in end, however i tried to calculate some values. Someone got ideas?(btw: all i got is only exp/required exp, no any values else)

Comment: add your code which lets us see the issue to search for what is wrong

Comment: You need to put your problematic code

Comment: There's no point or code required, it will looks like <progress attrs/> and i haven't script yet, i tried to get some values from calculator like: exp/expr*100(going to be like 99.452536 or like that), when max value in progress is 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common approach is to display the EXP required to reach the next level, rather than the current aggregate EXP. To reference the example you gave, rather than filling the EXP bar from 2431375 to 2438402, you can make the EXP bar fill from 0 to 7027 (the difference of EXP requirement between the two levels).

This way, the EXP bar will always show a clear progress towards the next level.